# Hide modules from a specific blog page

Tags: module

I made a new page https://www.anavasis.gr/blog/peer-to-peer-lending but on the position sidebar - c, I have some modules that are important for the rest articles in the blog but not for that one. How can I hide those modules from a specific article in the category blog?

---

Here you can see a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Hi sakis, welcome to JSE; please take our [tour].  Because, eventually, your live site will be fixed, it is important that you capture the site's state in this point in time so that your question makes sense (permanently).  Please take a screenshot of your site (and potentially scribble on it) to show future readers what the page is like and how you'd like it to be.  When you have the image ready, you can [edit] your question at any time.  When you edit, please capitalise the word `i` to `I`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to display or hide modules within Joomla by following these steps:

1. on the Left nav menu, click on "content", then "Site Modules"
2. Clicking on Site Modules should display the site modules in the main content area.
3. Select the module you want to display or hide.
4. On the Menu Assignment tab, There is a Module Assignment dropdown with several options including "On all pages", "No pages", "only on the pages selected", and "On all the pages except those selected".
5. Selecting "only on the pages selected" or "On all the pages except those selected" will will let you choose which pages this module is displayed.

This should let you display or hide the specific modules on the peer-to-peer-lending article.

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer but this is not possible when the article is in anavasis.gr/blog because i cannot find any place in the backend where i can hide modules from specific blog articles. Blog articles are taking modules all together please see below picture

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/GNUNzvjq0q

Answer (score 0):

Modules are displayed depending on the menu ID. Blog articles inherit the menu ID of the blog menu item so the same modules are displayed.

The normal way around this issue is to create a "hidden" menu item for each blog article which might be a reasonable solution if you don't have too many blog articles.

Alternatively, a third party extension such as Advanced Module Manager might help.

Another option is to create a template override with suitable code to display particular modules depending on whether this is a blog page or an article page and the article ID if needed.